# When sending message from remote actor to Spark actorStream, connection always disconnect

Tags: apache-spark, akka, spark-streaming, akka-remote-actor

When Sending message from remote actor to spark, the heart beat will always fail:

Logs at remote node:

[INFO] [03/23/2015 22:13:33.591] [wtb-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6] [akka.tcp://wtb@127.0.0.1:2552/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FsparkDriver%40127.0.0.1%3A7777-1] No response from remote. Handshake timed out or transport failure detector triggered.

[WARN] [03/23/2015 22:13:33.605] [wtb-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-5] [akka.tcp://wtb@127.0.0.1:2552/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FsparkDriver%40127.0.0.1%3A7777-0] Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@127.0.0.1:7777] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].

Logs at Spark node:

15/03/23 22:13:33 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://wtb@127.0.0.1:2552] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].

What I missed caused these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark disable Akka heart-beat by default. It is set to be 1000 seconds. Set the heart-beat interval fix this problem.